# Java Spring Boot - JPA : StackOverflowError with a @ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stack-overflow

I am currently developing an application with the API in JavaSpringBoot and I need to add relationships between users (friends). For this I made a many-to-many relation which contains two fields:

```java
CREATE TABLE friend_relation
(
    fk_id_friend   integer REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
    fk_id_user     integer REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (fk_id_friend, fk_id_user)
);
```

When I connect with a user and add relationships :  everything is fine, but if I connect to one of the accounts added as a friend by the other user, there is a StackOverflowError.

I know it's because of the almost identical entries in the database, but I have no idea how to get my entity to be correct.
Currently each user must add the other individually, I imagine that I have to make a friend request system but again I am blocked.
Do I have to make an "effective" field in my friend_relation table. If so, how do I use it? Should I create a specific entity for this table or leave it in the User entity?

Currently, this is what my user entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_generator", sequenceName = "users_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    [...]

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "friend_relation",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_user", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_friend", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    )
    private List<UserEntity> friends = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When trying to modify my entity to avoid the error:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="friend_relation",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_id_user"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_id_friend")
    )
    private List<UserEntity> friends;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="friend_relation",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_id_friend"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_id_user")
    )
    private List<UserEntity> friendOf;
```

I looked for resources on the internet but I did not find it, I may have searched poorly and I apologize in advance if the answer has already been given.

If you can help me it is with great pleasure, thank you in advance!
(And sorry for the Google Translate I preferred not to use my rough English)✌

---

Ok sorry update, i don't post the stake trace : https://pastebin.com/Ls2qRpU4

It happens when I get my user on the front side. I am trying to connect but I cannot because this error occurs.

Comment: You say you get a StackOverFlowError. Where does it happen? Can you please post the StackTrace?

Comment: Hi, ty i edit my post with the stake trace !

Answer (score 3):

First of, I've noticed an `@Data` on your entity, which I suppose is from Project Lombok? Just be careful, Lombok generated methods can trigger lazy loading and there are problems with equals/hashCode for auto-generated IDs. (see [here](https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/) and [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/))

Now to your problem:

It's indeed a JSON serialization issue. You have circular references and Jackson runs in circles bc. it doesn't know where to stop.

You can either use a DTO projection where you resolve this circle yourself, like:

```
public class UserDto {
    public Integer id;
    public List<Integer> friends; // List of IDs
}
```

You can also use Jackson annotations to achieve almost the same thing, like `@JsonIdentityInfo`. [Here's an article about it.](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
    property = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_generator", sequenceName = "users_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    [...]

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "friend_relation",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_user", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_friend", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    )
    private List<UserEntity> friends = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When you have complex Entities with circular references or very large object trees, you often have to think hard about how to serialize them - especially when taking LazyLoading into account. I have spent a **lot** of time on this in complex professional projects. Simple automatically generated DTOs and serialization sometimes don't cut it.

Comment: Whether that solution works for you depends on how you want to consume that JSON, i.e., that defines what data you need in your projection.

Comment: Yes regarding the Lombok warnings and encouragement to think the modeling through. I've spent now so much time fiddling around with Hibernate mappings, my go to solution is to cut off full object references as much as possible and take away all responsibility from hibernate for joint storing; it means a bit more code to take care of that yourself, but the code makes it obvious what's happening and you spend way less time dealing with all these Hibernate issues.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather keep a clear and complete data model and treat the DB as ground truth. For my presentation layer, I use queries that give me DTOs which can be trivially serialized to JSON. Fetching only what you need and all of it with one query results in very good performance. E.g. see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working 
I am a beginner and I sometimes find it difficult to grasp certain concepts and also understand the documentation (because not in my native language). I also use DTOs to communicate with the front and keep only the necessary information

Comment: No worries! JPA can be very confusing and complicated, also for advanced users! Especially when tuning performance of a real system. I've learned an awful lot by following Vlad Mihalcea's Blog and Twitter. He is also very active on here.

Comment: Okay, I tried all afternoon but I still have stackoverflow errors and it is starting to swell. I think I will drop this feature because there are plenty of places where nothing works with the changes made
I have this error in one page when i try to change the relation between users : [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/YszFzP9M)
and this when i ty to display people list : [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/CWXHgkVY)
The (UserEntity.java:18) is @Data so I think that's the cause of the problem, I'm going to dig on this side but meh...

Comment: Well, if you upload a minimal reproducible example to, e.g., Github I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

I put the importants files in this [repo](https://github.com/Squify/app-minimale) (and i have Mappers but i don't use them in these files ..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216747/discussion-between-benjamin-maurer-and-pauline).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert on this, so I'm sure others will give more accurate answers. However, the problem seems to occur when mapping the entity to JSON. You can't map to JSON a user with a collection of friend users that also have their friends in a fully mapped collection since that causes infinite recursion. I would try to use Jackson annotations to make the serialization of the friends list produce a list of ids instead of a list of complete users.

Comment: That's right. Please provide at least a reference where she can find some documentation. But better would be to add some code

Comment: This is offtopic, but I'll ask because I don't participate much in StackOverflow. Should I, then, refrain from giving an answer at all when I'm unable or unwilling to fill in all the details?

Comment: Maybe posting such as a comment would be a good advice.